# While loop with tables C

Tags: c, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define N 30
int main()
{  char c, y, input[N];
int X, i=0, j;
printf("Give displacement\n");
scanf("%d",&X);
printf("Give chars\n");

while(((c=getchar()) !=EOF) && (i<N-1)){
    input[i]=c;
    i++;

}
input[i]='\0';
j=0;
for(j=0; j<=i-1; j++){
    if (isalpha(input[j])){
        if (isupper(input[j]))
          y=(input[j]-'A'+X)%26+'A';
        else
          y=(input[j]-'a'+X)%26+'A';
        putchar(y);
    }


}
return 0;
}
```

hey all. well, this code doesnt seems to works as it should. It skips 2 positions at the table instead of one. Which makes the program unusable since i need a table of 30 positions. I think that the problem is in the while loop, but i really cant find it. Any help would be apprecieted. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific; from what I can guess, this program is functioning correctly, i.e. when given a bunch of characters and a displacement, it'll return the same characters "shifted" to the right (Caesar's cipher).

Comment: Just a style nit-pick: `for(j=0; j<=i-1; j++)` is more easily read as `for(j=0; j<i; j++)`. The first can be dangerous in other circumstances, for example when `i==0`

Comment: `char c` --> `int c` since that's the function `getchar()` return type, which must distinguish (in general) `EOF` from `255`. Variable `char y` would be better as `int y` too, because that's the argument type for `putchar()` and because `'A'` evaluates to an `int`.

Comment: Time to run a debugger and/or do some debug printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the call to `scanf`, there's a newline left in the input buffer.  That newline becomes the first character read by `getchar`.

To get the newline out of the buffer, add a separate call to `getchar` right after the `scanf` call:

```
scanf("%d",&X);
getchar();
```

That will give you the additional character you're missing.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, `c` should be defined as an `int` instead of a `char`, because `getchar` returns an `int`.  Otherwise, the test for `EOF` will always be false.

Answer (score 0):

if you want 30 characters you have to define N as 31

[0 - 29] + '\0'

In your first while loop i believe that the second test is wrong:

Use it like this:

```
while(((c=getchar()) !=EOF) && (i<=N-1)){
    input[i]=c;
    i++;
}
```